How to pass in a generic list to a method in c#
I have a Mediator class with a register pipeline method that takes a message type, a pipeline filter type, and a message handler type.
internal static void RegisterPipeLine<T1, T2, T3>()
      where T1 : IMessage
      where T2 : BaseFilter
      where T3 : IMessageHandler
  {
      var pipeLine = new PipeLine()
      {
          Filters = [typeof(T2)],
          MessageHandler = typeof(T3)
      };
      pipeLines[typeof(T1)] = pipeLine;
  }

Which I call like so
  Mediator.RegisterPipeLine<Message1, LogFilter, MessageHandler1>();

This works fine, except I want to have multiple pipeline filters. So far I've overloaded the RegisterPipeLine method like this
 internal static void RegisterPipeLine<T1, T2, T3, T4>()
        where T1 : IMessage
        where T2 : BaseFilter
        where T3 : BaseFilter
        where T4 : IMessageHandler
     {
         var pipeLine = new PipeLine()
         {
             Filters = [typeof(T2), typeof(T3)],
             MessageHandler = typeof(T4)
         };
         pipeLines[typeof(T1)] = pipeLine;
     }

Which I call like
 Mediator.RegisterPipeLine<Message2, LogFilter, ValidFilter, MessageHandler2>();

But I don't want to have to create a specific overload for every number of filters I want in the pipeline.
Is there a way to do this nicer?

Well how much variance will/can there be? will there be more MessageTypes at some point, or can there only be more filter and handler types?

Your RegisterPipeLine method doesn't look like it needs to be generic in the first place. Why not have your callers supply only Type params?

@Dai Generic constraints.

There are just more filter types. The idea is that the pipeline is per message type, and the pipe line consists of multiple filters and one handler.

@JohnathanBarclay Those could be done at runtime too (Type.IsAssignableFrom...) - the only thing you'd miss-out on is compile-time errors - that might be an acceptable trade-off if the problem is the OP wants variadic args.

This would probably benefit from the builder pattern, then as many filters can be applied as necessary.

Add a IEnumerable<BaseFilter> filters parameter then, and derive Filters = filters.Map( flt => flt.GetType() ).ToList().

BTW, consider using type-parameter names like TMessage and TFilter instead of T1 and T2.

@Dai But then you'd need instances of BaseFilter, which defeats the purpose.

@JohnathanBarclay ...or IEnumerable<Type> filterTypes

@Dai You'd lose type safety though. Using a builder might be preferable.

@DavidKethel - This seems like a job for a linked list. Why not use one?

You might use something like the builder pattern:
public class PipelineBuilder<TMessage,TMessageHandler>() where TMessage: IMessage, TMessageHandler : IMessageHandler
{
   private List<Type> filters = new List<Type>();

   public PipeLineBuilder<TMessage,TMessageHandler> WithFilter<TFilter>() where TFilter : BaseFilter
   {
      filters.Add(typeof(TFilter));
      return this;
   }

   public void Register()
   {
      var pipeLine = new PipeLine()
      {
          Filters = filters,
          MessageHandler = typeof(TMessageHandler)
      };
      pipeLines[typeof(TMessage)] = pipeLine;
   }
}

Usage is
 new PipelineBuilder<Message2, MessageHandler2>()
       .WithFilter<LogFilter>()
       .WithFilter<ValidFilter>()
       .Register();


How do you intend for the pipeLines dictionary to work in this solution?

I think this would work with adding a helper class and an interface (for covariance) to achieve full compile time safety.
The cost for me is negligible as we instantiate empty objects that won't put too much pressure on the GC.
public class TypeOf<T> : ITypeOf<T> {
    public Type Type => typeof(T);
    public static TypeOf<T> Get => new TypeOf<T>(); // convenience
}

public interface ITypeOf<out T> {
    Type Type { get; }
}

internal static void RegisterPipeLine<T1, T2, T3>(params ITypeOf<T2>[] baseFilters)
      where T1 : IMessage
      where T2 : BaseFilter
      where T3 : IMessageHandler
  {
      var pipeLine = new PipeLine()
      {
          Filters = baseFilters.Select(x => x.Type).ToList()
          MessageHandler = typeof(T3)
      };
      pipeLines[typeof(T1)] = pipeLine;
  }

Usage is
RegisterPipeLine<,BaseFilter,>(TypeOf<LogFilter>.Get, TypeOf<ValidFilter>.Get);


Why don't you prefer to use params keyword? If you do so, we can handle multiple filters without creating separate overloads for each number of filters.
internal static void RegisterPipeLine<TMessage, THandler>(params Type[] filterTypes)
    where TMessage : IMessage
    where THandler : IMessageHandler
{
    var pipeLine = new PipeLine()
    {
        Filters = filterTypes,
        MessageHandler = typeof(THandler)
    };
    pipeLines[typeof(TMessage)] = pipeLine;
}

We can call as such.
Mediator.RegisterPipeLine<Message1, MessageHandler1>(typeof(LogFilter), typeof(ValidFilter));

By doing so, we can call with any number of filter types.

main issue is that we don't get compile time check to make sure that the params of Type are actually all derived from BaseFilter, like we do with a bit of extra work in my answer.

@tinmanjk, there is no excellence, and there are always drawbacks when there are advantages.

one can strive for it. OP could have overloaded to Func<T1,T2,T3...> style but then again wondered if something could be done...compile time.

If I were you, I would prefer to use the Chain of Responsibility pattern for filter. It's more nature for your implementation example.
public abstract class BaseFilter
{
    public abstract bool Filter();
}

public abstract class BaseFilter<T>: BaseFilter where T : BaseFilter, new()
{
    private readonly T _innerFilter;

    protected BaseFilter()
    {
        _innerFilter = new T();
    }

    public override bool Filter(IMessage message) 
    {
        _innerFilter.Filter(message);
        return true; //// e.g.
    }
}

This will give you flexibility of using different filters in conjunction with each other.
As for example
public bool Filter(IMessage message)
{
    return _innerFilter.Filter(message) && message.Contains("test"); //// e.g.
}

Your call side of the code won't change, and it might look like
Mediator.RegisterPipeLine<Message1, ValidFilter<LogFilter>, MessageHandler1>();

More about this patter. The implementation of this pattern for your case might be different and look like builder that also described here.

Here is my take on it. Using two builders.
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new PipelineBuilder();
    builder
        .AddPipeLine<Message1, MessageHandler1>()
            .WithFilter<LogFilter>()
            .WithFilter<ValidFilter>();
    builder
        .AddPipeLine<Message2, MessageHandler2>()
            .WithFilter<LogFilter>();

    var pipelines = builder.Build();
}

public class PipelineBuilder()
{
    private List<(Type message, Type handler, FilterBuilder builder)> items = new();

    public IFilterBuilder AddPipeLine<T1, T2>()
         where T1 : IMessage
         where T2 : IMessageHandler
    {
        var filterBuilder = new FilterBuilder();
        items.Add((typeof(T1), typeof(T2), filterBuilder));

        return filterBuilder;
    }

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, PipeLine> Build()
    {
        var pipelines = new Dictionary<Type, PipeLine>();
        foreach (var (message, handler, builder) in items) 
        {
            pipelines.Add(
                message, 
                new PipeLine()
                {
                    Filters = builder.Filters,
                    MessageHandler = handler
                });
        }
        return pipelines;
    }
}

public class FilterBuilder : IFilterBuilder
{
    public List<Type> Filters { get; } = new();

    public IFilterBuilder WithFilter<T>() where T : BaseFilter
    {
        Filters.Add(typeof(T));
        return this;
    }
}

public interface IFilterBuilder
{
    IFilterBuilder WithFilter<T>() where T : BaseFilter;
}


I hate seeing return this; in fluent code. It leads to nasty bugs. Returning a new FilterBuilder with a newly created List<Type> Filters is a far better choice.

@Enigmativity Why would it lead to bugs? Returning this or having an extension method on IFilterBuilder with the WithFilter function that returns the this parameter instead is usually how I do it.

If you have a builder like this var b = new B(); var x = b.X(); var y = b.Y(); then returning this means that the y object also contains the X() call. LINQ doesn't work that way. If you always return a new instance then x and y would be independent, but you can't tell that from my example code.

Doing public class B { private B _inner = null; public B() { } public B(B inner) { _inner = inner; } public B X() => new B(this); public B Y() => new B(this); } avoids the issue.

@Enigmativity This is pretty standard way of doing it. Similar to for example how the WebApplicationBuilder works. Adding services: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.cs

Yes, I agree a lot of people use a poor approach. LINQ gets it right.
